# Problems with SHORTCUT ICON in HTML

Tags: html, web, icons

I'm trying to create a website with a shortcut icon. Although I have looked online and I have used the code for it, it still doesn't work. Could anyone help me?
Code:

```
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/PICTURES/favicon.ico" />
```

Is there anything wrong with this? Please help.

Comment: the suggestion is to use only lower case strings both in the rel attribute (see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-hyperlink-rel) and in the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your favicon is correctly made? There are multiple websites on Google that you can use for that. Also, if you have used the name favicon.ico before, it could be it won't work correctly either. Try renaming your favicon to favicon2.ico or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN Documentaion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537656(v=vs.85).aspx) it needs to be in the <head> tag:

```
<head>
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://www.example.com/myicon.ico"/>
    <title>My Title</title>
</head>
```

Things that it may be:

1. You may need to have a title just in case
2. It might not allow for dynamic references (i.e. you can't say "/pictures/icon.png" - you may have to say "http://www.example.com/pictures/icon.png")

What you can do in Chrome (on any page with an icon) is right click and select "view source" -> I did it with this page and I can find it by just looking for "SHORTCUT ICON"

Comment: Shouldn't you put title before the link rel?

Comment: If you view source for this page, the shortcut icon is first.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. I always use title first. Thanks for that bit of info Quintin :)!